# Image of a morphism of an n-dim. variety with n-dim. tangent spaces on the target

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Assume we have a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a projective scheme $Y$ together with a morphism $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ such that

- $\phi$ is injective on closed points, that if $x\neq y$ in $X$ are closed points then $\phi(X)\neq\phi(Y)$.
- we have $\dim(T_{\phi(x)}Y)=n$ for all $x\in X\setminus D$ where $D\subset X$ is some smooth divisor.

What can we say about the image $\phi(X)$? Is it a (maybe generically) smooth irreducible component of $Y$?

The condition on the dimension of the tangent spaces on $X\setminus D$ looks like as if $V=\phi(X\setminus D)$ should be open in an irreducible component $Y_0$ of $Y$. So that $\dim(V)=\dim(Y_0)=n$ and $Y_0$ is smooth along $V$. But is this actually the case?

Or what can we say about $\phi(X)$ and $Y_0$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $Y_0$ the irreducible component of $Y$ containing $\phi(X)$. Any morphism between projective schemes is projective, hence proper. So $\phi(X)$ is closed in $Y_0$. Of course $\dim \phi(X)\le \dim X=n$, and since $\phi$ is closed and injective on closed points, $\dim\phi (X)\ge n$ (by the definition of Krull dimension), hence it is equal to $n$. Then $\dim Y_0\ge n$, and the condition on dimension of tangent spaces shows that $\dim Y_0\le n$, so it is also equal to $n$. So $\phi(X)=Y_0$.

By the condition on tangent spaces the component $Y_0$ is smooth on an open subset of it. It is not necessarily smooth everywhere, which is shown by the example of normalization of a cuspidal curve $y^2z=x^3$ in $\mathbb P^2$.